# How can I make jni.h file available to configure file?

Tags: java, configure

I'm trying to install java API to tokyo cabinet. But I get the following error.

```
$ ./configure

#================================================================
# Configuring Tokyo Cabinet for Java version 1.24.
#================================================================
checking MYJAVAHOME... 
checking JVMPLATFORM... ls: cannot access /include: No such file or directory

checking JAVAC... no
#================================================================
# WARNING: /bin/javac is not found.
#================================================================
checking for gcc... gcc

checking tcutil.h usability... yes
checking tcutil.h presence... yes
checking for tcutil.h... yes
checking jni.h usability... no
checking jni.h presence... no
checking for jni.h... no
configure: error: jni.h is required
```

where can I get jni.h file and where can I put it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Whatever system you're on doesn't have a JDK installed. You should install a JDK, which should also come with a jni.h file

Comment: does having javac on my system means having a JDK installed? or not? `javac` is on /usr/bin/.

Comment: typing `java -version` into my shell gives me `OpenJDK Client VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode, sharing)`. I have jdk, right?

Comment: It looks like a horrible configure script. It expects MYJAVAHOME to be set to wherever the JDK install is located. On the linux system I have, that means that I have to run it with `export MYJAVAHOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64; export CPPFLAGS=-I$MYJAVAHOME/include ./configure`